# HTML.DropdownList - having text field show values of multiple columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an dropdownlist like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryOptions",
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DeliveryOptions"])
```

This gets its data from the controller action like so:

```
var options = context.DeliveryTypes.Where(x => x.EnquiryID == enqId);
ViewData["DeliveryOptions"] = new SelectList(options, "DeliveryTypeId", 
"CODE" + " - " + "DeliveryPrice");
```

I'd like to have my dropdownlist display the `CODE + DeliveryPrice` in its text field, for example: 'TNTAM - 17.54' but I get the following error:

```
DataBinding: 'MyApp.Models.DeliveryTypes' does not contain a property 
with the name 'CODE - DeliveryPrice'.
```

My DeliveryType Model looks like so:

```
[Key]
public int DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
public string CODE { get; set; }
public decimal DeliveryPrice { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anonymous type:

```
var options = context.DeliveryTypes
    .Where(x => x.EnquiryID == enqId)
    .Select(x => new { Value = x.DeliveryTypeId, Text = x.CODE + " - " + x.DeliveryPrice });

ViewData["DeliveryOptions"] = new SelectList(options, "Value", "Text");
```

Or alternatively create a specific `CustomSelectListItem` class which you can reuse, which contains `Value` and `Text` properties which you can reuse for such occasions as this.